# Adding dynamic sub-rows by selecting tableview row in tableview iPhone errors?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I want to add row dynamically. I have tableview list of building names. If some one choose building(didSelectRowAtIndexPath) then respective floors of building should get added dynamically as subrow. Its like maximizing and minimizing the subrow on respective building list selection. How do I do this. Thanks in advance...

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
// There is only one section.
if (tableView == indoortable || tableView == indoortable_iPad)
{
    return 1;
}
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section    {
// Return the number of time zone names.
if (tableView == indoortable || tableView == indoortable_iPad)
{
    return [indoorZones count];

}

}
```

cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (tableView == indoortable || tableView == indoortable_iPad)
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]  initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;             //cell bg
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }       
    // Set up the cell.
    //cell.textLabel.text = [copyListOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text =[indoorZones objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
    //[cell setIndentationLevel:[[self.indoorZones objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] intValue]];
    return cell;
}
}
```

didSlectRowAtIndexPath method:

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath 
 {
zonesFloor = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
zonesFloorA = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Gr fl",@"1st fl",@"2nd fl",nil];

[zonesFloor addObject:zonesFloorA]; 
if (tableView == indoortable )
{

    NSUInteger i=indexPath.row+1;
    for (NSArray *count in self.indoorZones)  //app is crashing here giving  error.......Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x4b1d550> was mutated while being enumerated.
 {

        [zonesFloor addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
        [self.indoorZones insertObject:zonesFloor atIndex:i++];


    }

    [[self indoortable] beginUpdates];
    [[self indoortable] insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)zonesFloor  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [[self indoortable] endUpdates];

    }


if (tableView == indoortable_iPad )
{

    //some logic
}

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath animated:NO];
}
```

It Gives following error [__NSArrayI compare:]: Or [NSIndexPath _fastCStringContents:]:  unrecognized selector sent to instance.  I tried many ways but may be I am lacking somewhere. Please suggest. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath 
{
    //NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [self.indoortable indexPathForSelectedRow];
zonesFloorA = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Gr fl",@"1st fl",@"2nd fl",nil];

if (tableView == indoortable )
{
    for (NSString *str in zonesFloorA) {
        [indoorZones addObject:str];
   }
   //[[self indoortable] beginUpdates];
   //[[self indoortable] insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)zonesFloor  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
   //[[self indoortable] endUpdates];
}
if (tableView == indoortable_iPad )
{

//some logic
 }

  [tableView reloadData];

}
```

may this meet your requirement

Comment: It giving me error [__NSArrayI addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance ...

Comment: making it indoorZones Mutablearray now it is not showing in the tableview list

Comment: have you allocate it..i think you were allocating it by nsarray in viewdidload or where ??

Comment: Yes NSMutableArray *indoorZones = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initwithobject:@"A1".....,nil];

Comment: yaar declare your indoorZones in .h  (NSMutableArray *indoorZones) and alloc it like this in ViewDidLoad: 
indoorZones = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initwithobject:@"A1".....,nil];

Comment: Sorry for late response.........yes It is showing subrows but it is at the end of indoorZones array.........I want this under each row selection:) But still thanks a ton. If you do have time then advice me further logic

Comment: if it is working for you then you can accept it and vote it up and for further we can talk in chat room ...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13205/discussion-between-abhishek-and-navnath-memane)

Comment: Yet not got the tableview logic working:(    .....[UITableView insertObject:atIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: sorry friend i did not get the time to resolve your query really sorry brother.. if it is easy to you please do me mail like i can do something for you..

Comment: ok i will check it out.. as usual i don't have mac machine .. so will check it at evening .. and your welcome dear .:)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so not to sound mean, but there are almost too many issues here to count.

Let's start with a basic explanation of how tableView's work so that you can start to fix this:

***First, the tableView asks how many sections are in the table by calling:***

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

}
```

In your code, you simply tell it that it has one section.  However, in your later code, when you try to add rows to your table, you tell it that you want to add your rows to a second section (with an index of 1).  Therefore, you either need to add these rows to section 0 instead, or update the above method to tell it that, sometimes, there are two sections.

***Second, the tableView asks how many rows are in each section of the table by calling:***

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
             numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

}
```

In your code, you are simply returning the number of zones.  However, like above, you need to include the rows that you have added to your table.  If you are adding them to a different section, then you need to return different values, depending on how many rows are in the section with the index asked for in the `section` variable.  If they are all in the same section, then you need to add them up and return the correct value.

***Third, the tableView asks for an actual cell for the row by calling:***

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
                     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

}
```

In your code, you are only returning a cell which has data populated by the indoorZones array, but you also need to supply cells which are configured properly for the specific zone/floor.  Again, you either need to determine this by section number or row number as appropriate.

***Finally, when you click on a row, the tableview tells you by calling the following method:***

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
        didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath {

}
```

In this method, **you** need to update your data source that is used by the previous functions so that when they get called again, they will provide the correct data.  Your data source must mirror the way that you want your table view to look.  In your case, you have an array called indoorZones.  This is good if you just want to display a list of zones, which is what you start off doing.  However, when you want to add more rows, you need to add more rows to your data source first, so that when the tableView starts this process over, it is already there.

If you want everything to stay in one section, then I would come up with a data source that can include both types of rows, and be able to distinguish between them so that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` can create the proper type of cell and return it.

If you want two sections, then I would add a second array for the second section (since it is not the same type of data) and return the appropriate values in each of these methods, based on which array you need to use for that section.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I have done some changes and updated above code.......I am getting following error......Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x4b1d550> was mutated while being enumerated.. In console I can see the Row and Subrow get added but it is not displaying

Comment: You can't change an array when you are using fast enumeration on it.  Since you arent actually using the objects from indoorZones anyway, just change `for (NSArray *count in self.indoorZones)` to `for(int x = 0; x < [self.indoorZones count]; x++)`.

Comment: Hi...I have completed all modules in my application except above tableview thing. Every time I am getting new error. I want to share this module file with you, so could you plz give your mail ID.